# От какого слова образован глагол "штриховать"?

Tags: словообразование

Такой вопрос уже задавала, но не поняла ответ. Этот вопрос есть в заданиях олимпиады. Ответ *штрих* кажется лежащим на поверхности. Но неужели всё так просто?

Comment: Лара, зачем вы повторяете свой вопрос? Вам уже дан ответ в предыдущим вопросе.

Comment: _Серж: ...уже дан ответ в предыдущим вопросе_. === Но ответ-то там был дан неправильный (хоть и получил три положительных отклика)!

Answer (score 2):

> От какого слова образован глагол “штриховать”?

У Тихонова ("Словообразовательный словарь русского языка", М., 1990) так:

***штрих*** -> штрих-**ова**-ть -> штрихов-**к**-а

***штрих*** -> штрих-**ов**-ой

***штрих*** -> штриш-**ок**